# MINGW64 conditional syntax error that does not effect MINGW32

Tags: bash, shell, sh, git-bash

I have an issue where the following code works in a MINGW32 shell but not in a MINGW64:

```
if [[ ! -ne $FILTER ]]; then
    FILTER="--all"
fi
```

Produces the following error:

```
./PTCW.sh: line 72: conditional binary operator expected
./PTCW.sh: line 72: syntax error near `$FILTER'
./PTCW.sh: line 72: `if [[ ! -ne $FILTER ]]; then'
```

I have searched to find a solution but none that explains what I am seeing

Regards

Chad

Comment: `-ne` requires two operands. You've provided only one.

Comment: Thank you very much I have swapped the ! -ne usage for -z and this seems to work. Odd it worked in the 32/older version and not on the 64/newer version. Thank you for the help.